# C++ insertion more "\t" in a loop

Tags: c++, matrix, tabs, geometry

I would like to ask U about sign tab in C++.
I have a code, where upper triangle matrix is generated:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
double **a,slad,aslad;
int i,k,n;

cout<<"podaj n"<<endl;
cin>>n;
a=new double *[n];

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        a[i]=new double [n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                a[i][k]=2.0*rand()/RAND_MAX-1;
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
                printf("%10.5lf",a[i][k]);
                cout<<endl;
        }
}
```

/*TRIANGLE MATRIX*/

```
cout<<endl<<"Upper 1"<<endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
        cout<<endl;
        for(k=i;k<n;k++)
                printf("%10.5lf",a[i][k]);
}
```

When it is compiled, I see it without tabs at the beggining. Is it possible to create something like "i* /t" - you know... I'd like to add the proper number of tabs (it's the same like number of row - i) at the beggining of every row

It should look like :

```
1 2 3
  2 3
    3
```

not as it is now:

```
1 2 3
2 3
3
```

Could you give me some advices?

Comment: Print the tabs in a loop before printing the number?

Comment: I've seen something strange. 
I did what you've written, but there is example of my matrix

1.2333     1.2345     1.2455
       >>  0.5678  >>   0.9483
               >>>>   9.4356
Numbers aren't in the same column, they are starting before its right place. How can I repair it?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
cout<<endl<<"Upper 1"<<endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout<<endl;
    for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
         printf("\t");
    for(k=i;k<n;k++)
            printf("%10.5lf",a[i][k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to print the tabs before the characters. If you think about it the number of tabs you need will actually be the same as the index you are on (first you will need 0 tabs, next you will need 1 and so on). The following code should be put just before your print loop to achieve this.

```
for(l=0;l<i;l++)
{
    printf("\t");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use spaces to indent rows:

```
const unsigned width = 10;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%*s", i*width, "");
    for (k = i; k < n; k++) {
        printf("%*.5lf", width, a[i][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```